# When one compiles a `C` file in Visual Studio 2010, is it compiled as a C++ file?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

`C` and `C++` being different languages, and still I can compile them in Visual Studio 2010 under a C++ project. Why is that? Does the compiler interprets the `C` file as `C++` one instead?

Comment: use the /TP option for that

Answer (score 6):

No, it is compiled as C code.

A C++ project in Visual Studio can contain C++ and C code. The cl compiler recognizes the file extension and compiles it accordingly.

Files ending with .c are compiled as C code. Files ending with .cpp or .cxx are compiled as C++. This can be changed as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is compiled as C++ file, unless the source file has a ".C" extension

With a few exceptions, C syntax is also valid C++ syntax, so C source code will be often  compiled successfully by a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

C is not C++, but the two languages are designed in such a way as to maintain compatibility.

There is a certain common subset that allows one to write .h files which can be included in both C and C++ compilation unit; that is dependent on the language standards.

What's more important, although the standards don't stipulate it, they silently presume that on a given machine the two languages will share a so-called ABI - Application Binary Interface. That allows for calls to be done from one language into another.

Unlike languages like C#, Java, or VB.Net, which require all the files of a project to be compiled as a batch, C and C++ are based on the idea of individual compilation units. Therefore it is possible to include files of different types (C, C++, Asm) into a single project.

One can, however, look at it under another angle. I have a C# project where some C# sources are generated by T4. I can regard it as a project where the resulting assembly is made from C# files but the C# files themselves may be obtained by some preparatory steps such as T4 conversion.

In the same way, you can regard a C++ project as a project where the resulting assembly is made from *object* files, but the object files *may* be obtained by some preparatory steps such as compilation of C or C++ compilation units. And mind, you can include ready object files into your project as well (typically, in batches called libraries).

Answer (score 0):

no it is not compiled as c++, coz visual studio have support both c and c++ at a time..
if ur compile c program it is compiled as c only ... if u want to compile both in a single program you just add the header file of c and c++. (i.e) #include #include
,if u use both header you can compile both program at a time and also use printf scanf in c++ and u can use cin and cout in c programming.. thank you!